# Construct a portfolio of European call options with a certain payoff function

Tags: portfolio-management, european-options, replication, put-call-parity, payoff

My question is similar to [Replicate a Portfolio with Given Payoff](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/37419/replicate-a-portfolio-with-given-payoff) but I am not quite sure how to apply this to my problem.

A portfolio of European call options on an asset $S_T$ has a payoff function given by $V_T$ where:
$$V_T = 0,\ S_T < A$$
$$V_T = S_T - A , \ A \leq S_T \leq B$$
$$V_T = B - A, \ S_T > B$$

> (i) Construct a portfolio $H_1$ of European call options with this payoff function.
>
> (ii) Use Put-Call parity to construct a portfolio $H_2$ of European put
> options with this payoff function.

Answer (score 2):

You can check my answer to [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34887/finding-arbitrage-opportunity/34888#34888) for general details on how to solve this kind of problem.

Let $C_X(S_T)$ and $P_Y(S_T)$ be a call and a put option with strikes $X$ and $Y$ respectively, then:
$$\begin{align}
(\text{i}) \quad V_T &= (S_T-A)1_{\{A\leq S_T\leq B\}}+(B-A)1_{\{S_T>B\}}
\\
&=(S_T-A)1_{\{S_T\geq A\}}+(B-S_T)1_{\{S_T\geq B\}}
\\
&=(S_T-A)1_{\{S_T\geq A\}}-(S_T-B)1_{\{S_T\geq B\}}
\\
&=\max(S_T-A,0)-\max(S_T-B,0)
\\
&=C_A(S_T)-C_B(S_T)
\\
&=H_1
\end{align}$$
Using Put-Call parity:
$$\begin{align}
(\text{ii}) \quad V_T &=C_A(S_T)-C_B(S_T)
\\
&=\left(P_A(S_T)+S_T-D_TA\right)-\left(P_B(S_T)+S_T-D_TB\right)
\\
&=(P_A(S_T)-P_B(S_T))+D_T(B-A)
\\
&=H_2
\end{align}$$
where $D_T$ is the discount factor from maturity $T$ to the present time.

Answer (score 1):

For question (i), you simply buy one EU call with strike A and sell one EU call with strike B - this is called a bull call spread.

Try using the put-call-parity to construct the corresponding bull put spread yourself.